# Can't push data to MariaDB database

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I have an issue, when I execute my function there is no data being stored in the table. My database connection is working as it should be, so no errors in communicating with the database itself. Here is my code:

PHP:

```
//function for creating a bet
function CreateBet() {

  //make variables global instead of local
  global $con;
  global $CharTick;
  global $hash;
  global $created_by;

  //infinite loop, no <= or >=
  for($cycle=0; ; $cycle++) {
    //define result - select coinflip table, gameid column and for what number to look
    $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM coinflip WHERE gameid = $cycle");
    //check if table 'coinflip' in 'gameid' contains an already existing number, looking
    if($result->num_rows == 0) {
      //if that number is not used, create it
      $sql = "INSERT INTO coinflip (gameid, hash_sha1, hash_original, created_by) VALUES ($cycle, $hash, $CharTick, $created_by)";
      $con->query($sql);
      //stop the for loop
      break;
    }
  }
}


//execute the function for creating a bet
CreateBet();
```

PHP code for creating a connection with the database:

```
//connect to mariadb
$con = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testing');

//check if connection is NOT alright
if (!$con) {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
//echo if the connection was alright
echo 'Connected to MariaDB';
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `coinflip` (
  `gameid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `winner` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `ticket` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `hash_sha1` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `hash_original` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `joined_by` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `coinflip` (`gameid`, `winner`, `ticket`, `hash_sha1`, `hash_original`, `created_by`,         `joined_by`) VALUES
('0', '', '', '', '', '', ''),
COMMIT;
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Why don't you put some echo's into your code to trace what it is doing? Like after `if($result->num_rows == 0) {` you could do: `echo 'Found ['.$result->num_rows.'] rows.<br>';`. Etc. Perhaps this way you can find out where it goes wrong? Perhaps you're already doing this, but always enable error reporting when trying to debug code.

Comment: You should also stop suppressing errors using @.

Comment: You should not be using `global`, you should pass any values as parameters if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to "quote" your string values:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO coinflip (gameid, hash_sha1, hash_original, created_by) 
        VALUES ('$cycle', '$hash', '$CharTick', '$created_by')";
```

You should test the result of `$con->query($sql);` to see errors:

```
if (!$con->query($sql)) {
    echo "Error: " . $con->error;
}
```

Also `gameid` seems to be an integer, so you could use an integer type for the `gameid` column, or also use quotes in :

```
$con->query("SELECT * FROM coinflip WHERE gameid = '$cycle'");
```

Finally, you could use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to avoid this kind of problem and possible SQL injections.